# How can I refactor that after_create callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, callback, refactoring

This is my after_create callback:

```
after_create { |f| if f.target.class.eql?(Question)  
        if f.target.user != User.current_user
          Notify.create_notify( Notify::QUESTION_FOLLOW, f.target.user, User.current_user, f.target) 
        end
      elsif f.target.class.eql?(User)   
        Notify.create_notify( Notify::USER_FOLLOW, f.target, User.current_user,f.target)  if f.target.can_mail_user(:follower) 
      end 
  }
```

I tried move that to a block so now it looks like below:

```
after_create do |f| 
  if f.target.class.eql?(Question)  
    if f.target.user != User.current_user
      Notify.create_notify( Notify::QUESTION_FOLLOW, f.target.user, User.current_user, f.target) 
    end
  elsif f.target.class.eql?(User)   
    Notify.create_notify( Notify::USER_FOLLOW, f.target, User.current_user,f.target)  if f.target.can_mail_user(:follower) 
  end 
end
```

What else I can do to improve that code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of that should go to `Notify`. I assume this is a `Follow` class. A useful question to ask yourself in refactoring is 'does this class need to know about this behavior?', and I think in this case the answer is no. Try doing something like this:

```
after_create do |f|
  Notify.create_notify(f.target.user, User.current_user, f.target)
end
```

...and the rest of the branching logic goes in Notify, whose job it is to figure out which notification to send.

Answer (score 0):

One way to improve it is to use the is_a? method as opposed to directly comparing the class names.  Also, the variable f is not descriptive enough.  Lastly, I'd create a new variable to store f.target so you don't keep repeating yourself.

For example:

```
after_create do |record| 
  target = record.target
  if target.is_a?(Question) 
    if target.user != User.current_user
      Notify.create_notify( Notify::QUESTION_FOLLOW, target.user, User.current_user, target) 
    end
  elsif target.is_a?(User)   
    Notify.create_notify( Notify::USER_FOLLOW, target, User.current_user, target)  if target.can_mail_user(:follower) 
  end 
end
```